# symfony 5 access_control ROLE_USER_IP no effect

Tags: symfony

```
security:
    enable_authenticator_manager: true
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#registering-the-user-hashing-passwords
    password_hashers:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface: 'auto'
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#loading-the-user-the-user-provider
    providers:
        users_in_memory: { memory: null }
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            lazy: true
            provider: users_in_memory

            # activate different ways to authenticate
            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#the-firewall

            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/impersonating_user.html
            # switch_user: true

    # Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
    # Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
    access_control:
        # - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        # - { path: ^/profile, roles: ROLE_USER }
        - { path: '^/', roles: ROLE_USER_IP, ips: [127.0.0.1, ::1] }

when@test:
    security:
        password_hashers:
            # By default, password hashers are resource intensive and take time. This is
            # important to generate secure password hashes. In tests however, secure hashes
            # are not important, waste resources and increase test times. The following
            # reduces the work factor to the lowest possible values.
            Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface:
                algorithm: auto
                cost: 4 # Lowest possible value for bcrypt
                time_cost: 3 # Lowest possible value for argon
                memory_cost: 10 # Lowest possible value for argon
```

my local built-in symfony server IP doesn't know ROLE_USER_IP parameter. I can set ROLE_USER_IPPPPP there is no error on URL as http://localhost:8000/test

how to refuse access from IP ::3 or 127.0.0.3 ?

Answer (score 0):

```
- { path: '^/internal', roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, ips: [127.0.0.1, 221.64.45.214] }
- { path: '^/internal', roles: ROLE_NO_ACCESS }
```

this is the solution to only accept request from IP as 127.0.0.1 or 221.64.45.214. Others match second rule (ROLE_NO_ACCESS)